# Disaster recovery plan for ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, disaster-recovery

I have been asked to create DR plan for Clearcase. I have the vobs backed up to the DR Server. What else would I need for DR?

Thanks

Comment: It depends if you plan to use ClearCase MultiSite or not. Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of DR infrastructure that I had to manage involved also [an SDRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrix_Remote_Data_Facility) mechanism in place in order to have a rela-time synchronization of the server content.
The idea of a DR is that it can take place at any time. Restarting the service in the other server wasn't enough. A [quick checkdb](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122748) was also required.

The other aspect was about keeping the same server name  (even if its physical server changes), which means updating the DNS servers quickly enough for a client to be able to contact the new ClearCase server.

I didn't have to deal with the view server (each client was its own view server)

A separate license server was also in place on the DR server (since the hostid differs, you need to reserve a few licenses for working during a DR with IBM Rational products).